# DDD - one Command raising few thin Domain Events - How to raise one fat ECTS Event from that situation

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-driven, domain-events

First, is it ok in DDD that one Command raises couple of thin Domain Events which all have just a field or two?

If yes, then how would you implement publishing fat ECTS as some Integration Event towards other interested bounded contexts?

Also, even that it is situation that there is just one **thin** Domain Event per Command. How would you implement raising of ECTS from that Domain Event while avoiding refetching whole aggregate to just assemble ECTS event?